# django {{ STATIC_URL }} doesn't work sometimes

Tags: django, configuration, django-staticfiles

A pathetic django beginner has got a blocker problem to access static files (css, js) on some views. Mainly, on the homepage those static files are perfectly accessible, but on a different page, it doesn't and the layout is totally broken.

This is my settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'bands',
    'lyrics',
    'articles',
)
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "static"),
)
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
```

This is part of my base generic template which views extend:

```
<link rel="Shortcut icon" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/favicon32.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}js/sortable.js"></script>
```

When rendered, it return such code (and this is what I want):

```
<link rel="Shortcut icon" href="/static/img/favicon32.png" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/static/css/bootstrap.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/sortable.js"></script>
```

This is the code of the homepage view (the one that static files work):

```
def slider(request):
    context = Context ({ 'articles': Article.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:5] })
    return render(request, 'articles/slider.html', context)
```

and this is the view that doesn't access static files (it uses pagination example found on django docs):

```
def archive(request, page="1"):
    articles_list = Article.objects.all().filter(active=True)
    paginator = Paginator(articles_list, 6)
    try:
        articles = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        articles = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        articles = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context = Context({
        'articles': articles
    })
    return render_to_response('articles/archive.html', context)
```

If anyone has a guess what might be wrong, please let me know.

The code of current project is available as a [github repo](https://github.com/tkoomzaaskz/djninja).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use the [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext):

```
from django.template import RequestContext

def archive(request, page="1"):
    # ...
    return render_to_response('articles/archive.html',
                              context,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Or use the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#django.shortcuts.render) shortcut, it is like `render_to_response`, but uses `RequestContext`:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def archive(request, page="1"):
    # ...
    return render('articles/archive.html', context)
```

Note you used `render` in your `slider` view.

Answer (score 0):

[1] Add your directory name to INSTALLED_APPS in which the static directory is located.

[2] load static in your html template

[1] For Example [I have static in TestAPP]  [Check out this link]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHEck.png

[2] Then [load static files in your HTML Template as following]
: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vPkFb.png