# cannot access static files in Django

Tags: python, css, django, static-files

I'm struggling with static files in Django.

The structure of my project is as follows:

**search** (root folder with manage.py inside)

.....**search** (project folder with settings.py, urls.py and so on)

...........**templates** (HTML templates inside)

...........**static** (static files like css inside)

**HTML template content**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'search.css' %}"/>

**url.py content**


**from** django.contrib.staticfiles.urls **import** staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()

**settings.py content**

import os.path

SITE_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/aga/Auctions/search/search/'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ((os.path.join(SITE_ROOT,'/static/'),)
```

Which setting is wrong in this configuration?

Comment: you have only on static folder so. Try it this way. you don't have to write staticfiles_dirs

STATIC_ROOT='/home/aga/Auctions/search/search/static/'

Comment: do you need to run collectstatic?

Comment: @Sawan: I understand that you suggested to remove this STATIC_ROOT settings? I removed it but CSS is still not used by the browser :/

Comment: you have to keep STATIC_ROOT. i was suggesting to change the static_root as stated in previous comment.

Comment: **Check out this may be it will sort out** https://stackoverflow.com/a/65402431/13249628

Answer (score 0):

In settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'static_cdn')
```

Now create a folder named static inside your projects app and run the collectstatic comand. Then you can create your own static files inside the static folder and use in your templates.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to look here for clear process [Managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/)

in urls.py correct format should be

```
from django.conf.urls.static import staticfiles_urlpatterns
```